# Некоректная замена символов в строке

Tags: c++

Программа должна заменять любой знак препинания на "!". Проблема в том что заменяются любыем символы.

```
    //Замена в строке знаков препинания на "!"

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void replace(char* str) {
    int quantity = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ',' , '?' , '.' , ':' , ';') {
            str[i] = '!';
        }
        cout << str[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char str[1000];
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    cin.getline(str, 1000);
    replace(str);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот это чудо: `if (str[i] == ',' , '?' , '.' , ':' , ';')` замените на серию сравнений, объединённых логическим ИЛИ

```
if (str[i] == ',' || str[i] == '?' ....)
```